# element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML changes layout in Firefox 4

Tags: html, firefox, rendering, firefox4

I found a strange issue when browsing the older Ext documentation, http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.1/docs/?class=Ext.grid.PropertyGrid

The layout of the inheritance box (top right) is somewhat shattered.

[broken layout http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/374/bildschirmfoto20110427u.png](http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/374/bildschirmfoto20110427u.png)

But after executing

```
var resblock = document.getElementById('docs-Ext.grid.PropertyGrid').getElementsByClassName('res-block-inner')[0];
resblock.innerHTML = resblock.innerHTML; // should be a no-op(?)
```

everything is okay.

[okay layout http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/374/bildschirmfoto20110427u.png](http://img204.imageshack.us/img204/374/bildschirmfoto20110427u.png)

How can that be? A bug in Firefox 4?

---

*Edit*
A minimal testcase: http://jsfiddle.net/uZ3eC/

Comment: There are lots of cases in which setting `x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML` is not a no-op.  In particular, any time the DOM is something that can't be produced by the parser.  As a simple example, if you create a DOM in which a `div` has an `img` child and that `img` has a textnode child and then set the `innerHTML` of the `div` to itself, the result won't match what you had before you set innerHTML.

Comment: @Boris: I verified your example, but I think that is a bug, since [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-html5-20080610/serializing.html#html-fragment) say "If current node is an [...] img [...] element, then continue on to the next child node [of the div, that is] at this point.", so the `img`'s child nodes are supposed to be skipped in the serialization.

Comment: You're saying the same thing that Boris is. That the children of an `img` element are lost at serialization time, so serializing and reparsing won't get you back to where you started. i.e. It's not a no-op.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it looks like <del>a bug in</del> the way Firefox 4 <del>, over the handling of</del> handles line endings.

The resblock element is a `<pre>` element containing a number of text nodes, which deal with new lines and indentations. When they are constructed through the scripts, they contain a CARRIAGE RETURN (U+000D) followed by a sequence of non-breaking spaces.

However, after running `resblock.innerHTML = resblock.innerHTML;` they now contain a LINE FEED (U+000A) followed by the non-breaking spaces.

It seems that Firefox 4 is only treating the line feed character as a line break, and rendering the parts of the class hierarchy on new lines.

Edit: What Boris said.

The HTML5 draft spec Section [8.2.2.3 Preprocessing the input stream](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/parsing.html#preprocessing-the-input-stream) says:

> U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR) characters
>   and U+000A LINE FEED (LF) characters
>   are treated specially. Any CR
>   characters that are followed by LF
>   characters must be removed, and any CR
>   characters not followed by LF
>   characters must be converted to LF
>   characters. Thus, newlines in HTML
>   DOMs are represented by LF characters,
>   and there are never any CR characters
>   in the input to the tokenization
>   stage.

Comment: Actually, sounds like the Firefox 4 behavior is correct.  HTML5 requires that at parse time lone CR be converted to LF.  So if you inject a CR into the DOM manually (something that can't be done via the parser; only via scripts), then you create a DOM that won't round-trip when serialized and reparsed.

Comment: Good point, but I want to point out that the HTML in my example has not been produced by a script ([raw source with same issue](http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.2.1/docs/output/Ext.grid.PropertyGrid.html)), so the parser is supposed to convert the line feeds in the first run(?)

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - "Preprocessing the input stream" happens *before* the conversion of character references. So while there are no CRs in the input to the tokenizer, `&#13;` will still become a CR character token in the tree construction stage, and therefore in the DOM. Serializing and reparsing, as per innerHTML, will then convert them to LF characters according the "Preprocessing the input stream" rule.

Comment: Ah, yes,  I'd forgotten that you can inject CR using character entities too, not just scripts....

Comment: Aha, I finally got it ;) Looks like the input stream processing algorithm is somewhat inconvenient in this case.